# Expo - FCM with Google App Signing and Expo signing

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I am uploading my first Expo app to Google Play. During uploading progress, I Opt-in to Google App Signing. My understanding is that this is Recommended approach and this process will remove Expo signature and sign with Google certificate.

I am using FCM for push notification. Initially, when I configured FCM, I had Certificate fingerprints hash as Expo certificate hash. Now, in Production, my app will be using Google App Signing certificate which will be different.

So, the question is what is best practice for using FCM when Expo certificate is used for internal testing and Google App signing for Production. Google FCM does not allow Android with same package with two different fingerprints.